# Word replace in a string c

Tags: c, string, function, malloc

How to change this code to replace every appearance of a word in a string but won't replace all substrings. For example if the word is **ask** won't replace **task** or **asking**. So, for input: "I'm asking ask a task ask my friend" and the replace word: "for" the output should be: "I'm asking for a task for my friend".

```
char *replace_word(char *string, char *word, char *new_word) {
    int len = strlen(string) + 1;
    char *temp = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    int temp_len = 0;
    char *found;
    int len_w = strlen(word);
    while (found = strstr(string, word)) {
            if ((isalnum(*(found - 1))) || (isalnum(*(found + len_w)))) {
                    break;
            }
            else {

                    memcpy(temp + temp_len, string, found - string);

                    temp_len = temp_len + found - string;

                    string = found + strlen(word);

                    len = len - strlen(word) + strlen(new_word);
                    temp = realloc(temp, len * sizeof(char));

                    memcpy(temp + temp_len, new_word, strlen(new_word));

                    temp_len = temp_len + strlen(new_word);
            }
   }

    strcpy(temp + temp_len, string);

return temp;
  }
```

In this stage it's ok if the input is: "It's ask me this task?". The output is: " It's for me this task?" But if the input is something like this: "I'm asking this ask a friend", the output will be the same as the input, so the code doesn't make changes. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , so what happens is that after it found an occurrence of the word in a substring the while loop breaks;

```
if ((isalnum(*(found - 1))) || (isalnum(*(found + len_w)))) {
                break;
        }
```

Instead it should copy the word and everything before it so that the while doesn't go into an infinite loop because it's finding the same occurrence over and over again.
This change should make it work:

```
char *replace_word(char *string, char *word, char *new_word) {
    int len = strlen(string) + 1;
    char *temp = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    int temp_len = 0;
    char *found;
    int len_w = strlen(word);
    while (found = strstr(string, word)) {
            if ((isalnum(*(found - 1))) || (isalnum(*(found + len_w)))) {
          memcpy(temp + temp_len, string, found - string + strlen(word));

          temp_len = temp_len + found - string + strlen(word);

          string = found + strlen(word);

            }
            else {

                    memcpy(temp + temp_len, string, found - string);

                    temp_len = temp_len + found - string;

                    string = found + strlen(word);

                    len = len - strlen(word) + strlen(new_word);
                    temp = realloc(temp, len * sizeof(char));

                    memcpy(temp + temp_len, new_word, strlen(new_word));

                    temp_len = temp_len + strlen(new_word);
            }
   }

    strcpy(temp + temp_len, string);

return temp;
  }
```

Comment: You are welcomed , also another thing i forgot to mention is:
use while ((found = strstr(string, word))) to avoid any compiler warnings , written without parenthesis it checks the assignment return value which according to C99, section 6.5.16 is the value of the left operand after the assignment so it's exactly the same thing for C99 or newer compilers

Answer (score 0):

You have some other issues in the code, but:

```
       if ((isalnum(*(found - 1))) || (isalnum(*(found + len_w)))) {
                break;
        }
```

This is the core issue - once you identify that this word is surrounded by an alpha-numeric char, you want to skip to the next occurrence, but what you do here, is completely break the loop.

What you want to do is:

```
        if ((isalnum(*(found - 1))) || (isalnum(*(found + len_w)))) {
                continue;
        }
```

'break' **breaks** the loop.

'continue' **continues** to the next iteration.

Make sure to update the string after you find every occurrence, otherwise you'll be stuck in an endless loop of getting the same pointer over and over again from the strstr() function.

Comment: I realized that break ends my loop, but i didn't know how else to do. So it seems like i was missing the "update" when a word surrounded by alphanumeric was found. Thank you.